# Undo Autohotkey remaps after uninstalling

Tags: windows, macbook, autohotkey

So here's my situation, I have a Macbook running Windows 7 on Bootcamp.

When I first installed Windows 7, the Command key was the start key, and the Option key was the Alt key.

I decided to swap these two buttons to match the typical start key behaviour using AutoHotKey.

I've now decided I want to swap them back as I usually have to tap the option key twice to open the start menu and it's getting annoying.

Unfortunately I've found that I've uninstalled AutoHotKey for some reason a while ago, but the key swap is still active.

My question is: How can I revert this behaviour? My guess is that AutoHotKey modifies the registry, but I have no idea where to look for this.

Comment: Autohotkey does not control the scripts that are written with it - uninstalling autohotkey will not disable these scripts. Can you post the code to the mapping script? what location does this script/executable reside?

Answer (score 0):

The script itself does the mapping and the mapping should only be active while the script is running, not the AutoHotKey program. You can uninstall AutoHotKey from the Add/Remove Programs and still have a script running.

Is there anything extra down in the System Tray (near the clock)? If there is you can right click on it and exit it.

Did you add the script to the `Startup` folder so it is running each time you run Windows? If yes, remove the shortcut to the script.